# Is it possible to get different set of fields in Django form depend of user group membership

Tags: django-views, django-forms

I am new in Django and I am stuck in solving one problem. I have simple generic UpdateView and single model. I want to find a way to get different set of form fields or different forms depend of user group membership. In short when user member of group A click on edit button he get form with set of fields but when user member of group B click on the same button he should get different set of fields or different form.